# MariaDB Find the First Day of the Month and Convert to UTC

Tags: sql, datetime, timezone, mariadb, utc

I'm using MariaDB and my records are all stored in UTC however I want to be able to find those records that are within the previous 12 calendar months based on my local timezone.

Here's the steps I took:

```
SELECT
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS Current_Date_And_Time_In_UTC,
    CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),'UTC','Pacific/Auckland') AS Current_Date_And_Time_In_Auckland,
    DATE(CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),'UTC','Pacific/Auckland')) AS Date_In_Auckland,
    LAST_DAY(DATE(CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),'UTC','Pacific/Auckland')) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS Last_Day_Previous_Month_In_Auckland,
    LAST_DAY(DATE(CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),'UTC','Pacific/Auckland')) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY AS First_Day_Current_Month_In_Auckland,
    TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(DATE(CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),'UTC','Pacific/Auckland')) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY, MAKETIME(0,0,0)) AS First_Day_At_Midnight_Current_Month_In_Auckland,
    CONVERT_TZ(TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(DATE(CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),'UTC','Pacific/Auckland')) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY, MAKETIME(0,0,0)), 'Pacific/Auckland','UTC') AS First_Day_At_Midnight_Current_Month_In_UTC
```

This lead me to using this as my range:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT_TZ(TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(DATE(CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),'UTC','Pacific/Auckland')) - INTERVAL 13 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY, MAKETIME(0,0,0)), 'Pacific/Auckland','UTC') AS Start_DateTime_In_UTC,
    CONVERT_TZ(TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(DATE(CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),'UTC','Pacific/Auckland')) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY, MAKETIME(0,0,0)), 'Pacific/Auckland','UTC') AS End_DateTime_In_UTC
```

Is there a simpler way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a column of `timestamp` datatype, then no offsetting at all should be necessary.

The [documentation states](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/timestamp/#time-zones):

> If a column uses the `TIMESTAMP` data type, then any inserted values are converted from the session's time zone to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) when stored, and converted back to the session's time zone when retrieved.

Assuming that the timezone of your session is set to your local timezone, filtering the column against the last 12 months should be as simple as:

```
where myts >= date_format(current_date, '%Y-%m-01') - interval 12 month
  and myts <  date_format(current_date, '%Y-%m-01')
```